# prompt user a message and read input while saving it to a log file

Tags: linux, bash, shell, input

i have shell script that require to do following things:
1) shell script need to store the logs to a log file.
2) shell script need to prompt user with a message and reads the input.

Example:

```
cat read-test.sh
echo -n "What is your name?"
read user_name
```

Executing this script:

```
./read-test.sh >> read-test.log
```

Expected User prompt:

```
What is your name?
rajiv
```

When i execute this script as

> ./read-test.sh

i get the desired output.

but when i execute this script as

> ./read-test.sh >> read-test.sh

"what is your name?" is saved to read-test.log file which i don't want to.

Is there any way where i can show the user with message("what is your name?") and reads input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best answer depends on why you want to redirect like that, but one possible quick solution would be to change your `echo` line like this:

```
echo -n "What is your name?" > /dev/tty
```

Comment: the script that i am working on is also required to email the log file. so in order to send a mail, i need the log to be stored to a file.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `-p` option with `read`, which prints a prompt to standard error, allowing you to get rid of the `echo` statement altogether.

```
read -p "What is your name? " user_name
```

Since the prompt is written to standard error, it won't be included in `read-test.log` by the `>>` operator.